# Create symbolic links transforming file names - Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, transform

I have a bash script that will loop through a directory getting each file name. What I would like to do is create a few symbolic links for these files. Except I want to change the link names.

**Example 1:**

*File Name:* testFile.so.3.4.5

```
ln -s testFile.so.3.4.5 testFile.so.3
ln -s testFile.so.3 testFile.so
```

**Example 2:**

*File Name:* testLink.so.4.4

```
ln -s testLink.so.4.4 testLink.so.4 
ln -s testLink.so.4 testLink.so
```

So I need to transform the file name twice. The first time removing everything except the first number after `*.so`. The second time removing everything after `*.so`.

This is what I have so far. I know it's not much:

```
#! /bin/bash

# clear any info on screen
clear

# greeting
echo "Starting the script!"

# loop through all files in the directory
for f in *
do
    echo "Processing: $f"
done
```

I'm a bit new to bash and file name transformations, so any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a combination of bash [extended regular expressions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns) and [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

```
for file in *.so.*
do
regex='(.*\.so\.[^.]*)\..*'
if [[ $file =~ $regex ]]
then
  tempfile="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  ln -s "$file" "$tempfile"
  ln -s "$tempfile" "${tempfile%.*}"
fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

or more generally:

```
files='libfoo.so.1.2.3.4.5 libbar.so libqux.so.1'

for f in $files; do
  while test ${f##*.} != so; do
    link=${f%.*}
    ln -s $f $link
    f=$link
  done
done
```

this will create `libfoo.so.1.2.3.4 -> libfoo.so.1.2.3.4.5`, `libfoo.so.1.2.3 -> libfoo.so.1.2.3.4`, `libfoo.so.1.2 -> libfoo.so.1.2.3`, `libfoo.so.1 -> libfoo.so.1.2`, `libfoo.so -> libfoo.so.1`, and `libqux.so -> libqux.so.1`; libbar.so will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Also more generally, using only parameter expansion:

```
for f in *.so.*.*
do
  if [ -e "$f" ]; then
    base=${f%".${f#*.so.*.*}"}
    ln -s "$f" "$base"
    ln -s "$base" "${base%.*}"
  fi
done
```